# Assignment Operation Java

Tags: java

```
class string1 {
    static public void main(String[] ar) {
        String s1 = "test";
        String s2 = new String();
        if(s2=null) { // line 0
            System.out.println(s1);
            System.out.println(s2.length()); //Line 1
        }
    }
}
```

What i expected to happen was

a) s2 will be set to null because its an assignment operation as I am not using ==

b) And I will get a NPE at Line 1 during Runtime

and instead I got the following output as shown below.

Output is

```
if(s2=null)
     ^
  required: boolean
  found:    String
1 error
```

Can someone explain why I am getting compile error ?

Comment: Though i have mentioned solution of your question from jls, but for more detail please read 14.9.1 section of jls it will give better understanding.

Comment: Umm, this is an odd question.  Why wouldn't you just default the s2 value to null prior the if statement?

Answer (score 5):

Java will not implicitly cast to a boolean like some languages will. You must put an expression that evaluates to a boolean inside of conditional:

```
if ((s2 = null) != null) { }
```

This condition of course makes no sense, but it's the equivalent of what you're attempting to do. It's worth noting by the way that assignments should rarely be done in a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
if( (s2 = null) != null)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

The reason you are getting this error because you have to `explicitly` put the code for `boolean evaluation` in conditions as `Java doesn't implicitly cast it boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

An if-then statement is executed by first evaluating the Expression.

***From, JLS - Chapter14 : Blocks and Statements***

> 14.9.1. The if-then Statement
>
> An if-then statement is executed by first evaluating the Expression.
>   If the  result is of type Boolean, it is subject to unboxing
>   conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> If evaluation of the Expression or the subsequent unboxing conversion
>   (if any)  completes abruptly for some reason, the if-then statement
>   completes abruptly for the same reason.
>
> Otherwise, execution continues by making a choice based on the
>   resulting value:
>
> If the value is true, then the contained Statement is executed; the
>   if-then statement completes normally if and only if execution of the 
>   Statement completes normally.
>
> If the value is false, no further action is taken and the if-then statement  completes normally.

Answer (score 0):

You should note the fact that in java there are only two boolean values : `true` and `false` unlike some other languages which use `0` as false and anything else as true .

> Can someone explain why I am getting compile error ?

In an if statement the condition can either be true or false which are returned by comparison operations and by the boolean variables.

In,

```
if(s2=null)
```

the `s2=null` doesn't evaluate to any boolean value i.e, true or false therefore the compiler error :

```
required: boolean
  found:    String
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition evaluates only boolean conditions.

And the assignment operator does not give a boolean result here.

That is the reason for getting exception.

If you use `if ((s2 = null) != null)` instead of `if(s2=null)` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what everyone else said, s2 will *never* be null - you just assigned a new String to it! Are you sure you're not conflating string length/existence tests from other languages?